# List comprehension against tuple of sets

Tags: python, set, list-comprehension, python-3.5

Can someone please explain what is going on?

```
>>> xx = ({1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,2})
>>> yy = [x.discard(2) for x in xx]
>>> yy
[None, None, None, None]
>>> xx
({1}, {3}, {3, 4}, {4})
>>> id(xx)
4315823704
>>> id(yy)
4315797064
```

I'd expected `yy` to be equal to `[{1}, {3}, {3, 4}, {4}]` and `xx` to remain untouched!

Comment: Why would you expect that? `discard` removes the element from `x`, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @vaultah When I expand the list comprehension out I would have thought it would behave as follows: 
`yy = []
for y in xx:
   y = y.discard(2)
   yy.append(y)`

Comment: You can't expect a list comprehension to give you back results if you modify something in place - only the `return` value is logged as a result. You'll have to create a new copy of the dictionaries with the filtered elements and return that. So don't use `discard`.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan that is basically the same as above, just without intermediate step of assigning to y

Comment: Your misunderstanding is due to the fact that `discard` doesn't return anything. So your alternative syntax would *not* work either, because `y` would be None.

Comment: Mutating methods return None to reduce confusion of methods that return a new object and the ones that modify in place.

Comment: [`set.discard`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.discard) is a **mutating method** as in it removes the element from the set, not create a new set with it removed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the result that you want, you could use a list comprehension of the form:

```
yy = [x - {2} for x in xx]
```

For example:

```
>>> xx = ({1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,2})
>>> yy = [x - {2} for x in xx]
>>> yy
[{1}, {3}, {3, 4}, {4}]
>>> xx
({1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {2, 4})
```

Your original example behaves as follows:

```
>>> xx = ({1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,2})
>>> yy = []
>>> for x in xx:
...   # Here, x is a reference to one of the existing sets in xx.
...   # x.discard modifies x in place and returns None.
...   y = x.discard(2)
...   # y is None at this point.
...   yy.append(y)
...
>>> yy
[None, None, None, None]
>>> xx
({1}, {3}, {3, 4}, {4})
```

Comment: or just `[x - {2} for x in xx]`.